# Can't send json data over WebSocket (NODE JS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, websocket

After I created the .onopen event I made it launch some json data over, but I get an error,
Here is the code:

```
 ws.onopen = ('connect', function(connect) {
            let obj={};
            obj.name='data'
            message = 'connect';
            obj.body=message;
            var data = {"op": 0, "d": {"server_id": serverid, "user_id": author, "session_id": sessionid, "token": tokenn, "video": true, "streams": [
                {"type": "video", "rid": "100", "quality": -1}, {"type": "video", "rid": "50", "quality": 9223372036854775807}]}}, separators=(",", ":");

            ws.send(data.toString())
```

What I get:
node:events:368
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^

Error: read ECONNRESET
at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:220:20)
Emitted 'error' event on WebSocket instance at:

Comment: `data.toString()` is always just `[object Object]` If you want to turn your object into a string, use `JSON.stringify()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use "JSON.stringify(data)" for convert Object to string

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure this is your problem as the error looks unrelated.

But `data.toString()` will simply return `"[object Object]"`. You need to use `JSON.stringify(data)`

`ECONNRESET` usually means that the connection was unexpectedly closed. Maybe your server receives your payload and closes the connection somehow because it is `[object Object]` and not valid JSON?